# Completely lock a computer and force it to use a single application

Tags: windows-7, blocking

I'd like my windows 7 computer to use ONLY a single application developed in .net
No task manager, no nothing: just this single application automatically opening at startup.

I'd also like to have a special key combination or any other trick to enable another user to be normal administrator (with all the functions) for fixing problems (a computer tech account).

How can I achieve it using windows 7 technology or free products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common term is to make it into a `kiosk` style machine.

Then you can find a few guides via [a search engine](http://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20kiosk%20windows%207).

I found this guide that looks promising, uses local group policy to restrict applications being launched, that combined with your application starting up on initial log in sound like a good start

- http://sbs.seandaniel.com/2010/01/how-to-lock-down-windows-7-kiosk-or.html

More links

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555463
- http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-setup-windows-vista-and-7-as-a-kiosk/
- http://midspot.wordpress.com/2006/10/26/how-to-create-an-internet-kiosk-in-10-easy-steps/